# How to assign a string to an input field's content?

Tags: java, html, script-tag

The string value is being requested using script tags but I'm not sure how to add the value of `fibNum` to the input field's content.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

For example in java, the string variable's value can be added to a println statement as follows:

`system.out.println("The value is: " + fibNum);`

This is how I'm requesting the value, its then stored in a string variable called `fibNum`

```
<% String fibNum = request.getParameter("fibNum"); %>   
<input type="text" name="fibNum" size="40px" style="font-size:30pt;height:60px">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are using it in general (with no association of any BEAN) then scriplets wiht solve your query, as given by @Roberto

```
<% String fibNum = request.getParameter("fibNum"); %>   
<input type="text" name="fibNum" value="<%=fibNum%>" size="40px" style="font-size:30pt;height:60px">
```

But if you are using it with some bean and want to associate it under some session, it's always better use [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/el) and [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jstl).

```
<input type="text" name="fibNum" value="#{managedBean.funcReturningParam}" size="40px" style="font-size:30pt;height:60px">
```

`funcReturningParam` is the method which processes the values, both from frontend and backend, and then sets the parameters.

`managedBean` used should preferably 
 be the one with least security and debugging issues.

**PS**: Try to make a common function in any managed bean, which is to be used to get(set) values of most used parameters(variables) to be used and which are not associated with the DB Entities.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really used to webforms or java but in ASP.NET MVC with C# you could do this

```
<input type="text" name="fibNum" size="40px" style="font-size:30pt;height:60px" value="@fibNum">
```

I guess it's the same aproach, just adapt it to the language you're using.

Comment: The above solution doesn't work for a jsp page, in this implementation anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to show the `fibNum` value on the input text, you can do that with scriplets (what you are already using to declare and initialize the variable):

```
<% String fibNum = request.getParameter("fibNum"); %>   
<input type="text" name="fibNum" value="<%=fibNum%>" size="40px" style="font-size:30pt;height:60px">
```

Although, it is always better to use a templating solution like [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jstl) or [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/el) instead of Java scriplets.